# Dynamically Drop/Draw/Insert Command Button into Visio Page and set text using VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to drop/draw/insert a command button into a Visio page and set its text using VBA.

Currently I'm able to insert the button using the following VBA, but I'm not finding any way to edit the text.

```
' Generate Button
Dim generateButton As Visio.Shape
Set generateButton = migrationPlanPage.InsertObject("{D7053240-CE69-11CD-A777-00DD01143C57}", 0)
```

Below are two unsuccessful methods I've tried to set the button text value.

```
generateButton.CellsSRC(visButtonIcon, 0, visButtonCaption).Formula = "Test"
generateButton.Caption = "Test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
Dim obj As Shape
Set generateButton = ActivePage.InsertObject("{D7053240-CE69-11CD-A777-00DD01143C57}", visInsertNoDesignModeTransition)
generateButton.Object.Caption = "Hello"
```

Comment: Sadly this did not end up working either, still no text within the button.

Comment: It works, but you need to disable design mode transition on inserting control, otherwise the code would just stop there. I have updated the example.

Comment: Other than that, if you are adding a button to toggle layer, check out this topic: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3952.0. Or just use the layers plugin to do the job: https://bvisual.net/products/layermanager/

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply. I've attempted to disable design mode after inserting the control, however because on insertion it stops the VBA code it never gets to disable it. Is there another way around this? There appears to be limited documentation on the issue.

Comment: Check out the above code - I have updated the answer. there is flag, visInsertNoDesignModeTransition. You just run it using Run Macro (you can even close VBA IDE), it works.

Comment: Perfect, can confirm that this the addition of the flag worked. Cheers!